# Firestore serverTimeStamp inside array

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to make a document with a map inside of it.

```
 await admin.firestore().collection('myCollection').doc(specialID).set({

              'allOrders': [{timeStamp: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(), orderID: '1234', amount: 12, description: '1234'},],
            })
```

Above code WONT work, because admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() isn't supported inside an array.

Orders will be added later to that array & I would like to include a timestamp.

Is it possible to use another method (maybe epoch?) to indicate the time inside the array?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to assume that the clock is correct on the machine making the request to Firestore, you can simply use [`admin.firestore.Timestamp.now()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Timestamp.html#.now) to create a new timestamp with the current time on that machine.  Or you can even use the standard JavaScript `new Date()`, which Firestore will convert into a Timestamp field for you.